# An indicator showing when there are items one can review?

Tags: feature-request

(or remind me on which other meta site I should ask this...)

Would be great if the little 'review' link had some indicator when there were items for review. As it is, we have to click the review link. It would be spectacular if 'items available for review' showed up in the global StackExchange status/pulldown area on the left. :)